# LibreOffice Impress messes up letter spacing in Slide Show, design view looks normal

Tags: display, aspect-ratio, libreoffice-impress

On Windows, using LibreOffice 3.5.1.2, when I create a presentation using Impress, the Slide Show (<kbd>F5</kbd>) cuts off the bottom and top (similar to wide-screen movies) and thus changes the aspect ratio, messing up the fonts. What gets messed up in particular is the spacing between letters, which gets stretched a lot.

Here's how it looks during creation:

[image: Design-time view]

Here's how it looks on the screen with the preview (fine, too):

[image]

And now the messed up presentation as it appears on my screen (which has the same aspect ratio as our projector, 4:3):

[image]

I also noticed that the framing with the background you choose during initial creation of the presentation is not even shown on the last view.

How can I make sure that the aspect ratio (and consequently the inter-letter spacing and so on) remains the same, no matter what?

Comment: May I suggest to ask this at http://ask.libreoffice.org/questions/ ? I think you have better chances to get an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered over at [ask.libreoffice.org](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/2668). Thanks to phw for pointing it out. The behavior is actually a bug that was resolved in LibreOffice 3.5.3.

I have now installed this new version and everything works as expected.

The workaround for the old version 3.5.1 would be to **disable hardware acceleration** for the graphics card.